# python: how to change python-config into my current python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-config

My question is that,

if I run

```
which python
```

it returns

```
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

However, If I run

```
which python-config
```

It returns

```
/usr/bin/python-config
```

which is the built-in python 2.7 in macbook.

How can I change the config into the current python that I'm using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if there is a `python-config` or `python3-config` in `/opt/anaconda3/bin`. If there is a file named `python3-config`, you should run `python3-config` instead. If there is no `python3-config`, likely you don't have `python-config` installed for your conda environment. You can run `pip install python-config` (make sure you run pip under your anaconda environment).